Do android sources have soong module reference?
I need to view a soong module reference for android 10.
I can get a current reference from here. I am dealing with android 10 so I need those references can I find them in an android 10 sources build. Or are they also available at some other link online?

Apparently they do. I setup the build environment, lunched a device and executed make soong_docs. The docs are put to [$OUT_DIR/soong/docs/soong_build.html] as per the README.md in the soong sources directory
